# using fetch twice in php to get the data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get a data from db, I would to say welcome $row['name'];
then in a loop need to print the items

if I did the below code, I will get all items except the first item, but if I deleted the $row2 with the welcoming name, I will get all items why ?

is there a way to use this $row = $SQL->fetch() for both?

```php
<?php
session_start();


include "connect.php";
$access = isset($_SESSION["userid"]);
if ($access) {
    $SQL = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from items, users where userid = ?");
    $SQL->execute([$_SESSION["userid"]]);
    $row2 = $SQL->fetch();
    echo "Welcome " . $row2['name'] . "<br>";
    while ($row = $SQL->fetch()) {
        echo $row["itemname"] . "-" . $row["price"] . "-" . $row["itemqty"] . "<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<h1>Not Logged in. Access denied.</h1>";
}

?>
```

Comment: This query returns a Cartesian product. I doubt that that was your intention

Answer (score 2):

When you run `fetch()` you are moving forward the pointer in the result set. So your first call to `fetch()` gets the first row, second gets the second row, etc.

Probably the easiest approach would be to pull all results into an array and then work with that.

```php
<?php
session_start();


include "connect.php";
$access = isset($_SESSION["userid"]);
if ($access) {
    $SQL = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from items, users where userid = ?");
    $SQL->execute([$_SESSION["userid"]]);
    $data = $SQL->fetchAll();
    $row2 = $data[0];
    echo "Welcome " . $row2['name'] . "<br>";
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo $row["itemname"] . "-" . $row["price"] . "-" . $row["itemqty"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<h1>Not Logged in. Access denied.</h1>";
}
```